# How to fix solve Expected a 'for-of' loop instead of a 'for' loop with this simple iteration in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code problem when foreach  , I've seen a number of ways but nothing works

I have tried using the for-of but it didn't work

**This my component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../../_models/user';
import { UserService } from './../../_services/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from './../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxGalleryOptions, NgxGalleryImage, NgxGalleryAnimation } from 'ngx-gallery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-detail',
  templateUrl: './member-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-detail.component.css']
})
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  galleryOptions: NgxGalleryOptions[];
  galleryImages: NgxGalleryImage[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data['user'];
    });

    this.galleryOptions = [
      {
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px',
        imagePercent: 100,
        thumbnailsColumns: 4,
        imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
        preview: false
      }
    ];
    this.galleryImages = this.getImages();
  }

  getImages() {
    const imageUrls = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.user.photos.length; i++) { // The problem is here
      imageUrls.push({
        small: this.user.photos[i].url,
        medium: this.user.photos[i].url,
        big: this.user.photos[i].url,
        description: this.user.photos[i].description
      });
    }
    return imageUrls;
  }

}
```

**This my component end**

I want to display multiple images in one user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from your implementation of `ngOnInit`. Your are calling `getImages` outside of the subscription, then at the moment you call `getImages`, `this.user` isn't valued.

It should fix your issue :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data['user'];

    this.galleryOptions = [
      {
        width: '500px',
        height: '500px',
        imagePercent: 100,
        thumbnailsColumns: 4,
        imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
        preview: false
      }
    ];
    this.galleryImages = this.getImages();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

error in this line

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.user.photos.length; i++)
```

to

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.user.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks ok, but you can simplify it. You take photos from the user, which can be changed by the route, you should generate images every time when the user changed. And, why do not place this logic inside the constructor? In this example is make no sense to use `ngOnInit`, moreover, when `ngOnInit` is called, the DOM is already generated, what is the source of you problems. You should use `ngOnInit` when you need access to the component DOM, see description of the [angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

```
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  galleryImages: NgxGalleryImage[];

  galleryOptions: NgxGalleryOptions[] = [{
    width: '500px',
    height: '500px',
    imagePercent: 100,
    thumbnailsColumns: 4,
    imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
    preview: false
  }];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data['user'];

      this.galleryImages = this.user.photos.map(photo => ({
        small: photo.url,
        medium: photo.url,
        big: photo.url,
        description: photo.description
      });
    });
  }
}
```